# How do I get the path of a specific file in python

Tags: python, file, path, operating-system, subprocess

I need to get the path of a file. How do I do it? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
import subprocess
import os

file_name = "something.exe"
path = os.path.dirname(file_name)
print path
subprocess.call(path)
```

Comment: what are the params? why did you add a file_name when you didn't use it?

Comment: I fixed it, it was a mistake

Comment: ok, I see you have edited the post and it makes more sense. so I'm a little confused about your altimate goal. you have a file near where you are running the code and you want to get the full path for that?

Comment: The file is somewhere in the computer and I need to get the full path so the `subprocess.call()` will work.

Comment: ok so are you just using the file name and not its full path? how is the system supposed to know where it is then?

Comment: If the file could be anywhere on the computer you've got your work cut out, I guess a big os.walk could be used to search for it? Either way, likely to take ages.

Comment: because the user is suuposed to write the file_name and he does not know the path this is just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so what you want to do is to first locate the file with a os.walk() function:

```
import os
from os.path import join

lookfor = "file_name.exe"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    if lookfor in files:
        # found one!
        path = os.path.join(root,lookfor)
        print(path) #this is the path you required
        subprocess.call(path)
        break
```

but this will take a while and run the first file it found. also I assumed you have a windows, otherwise you should replace 'C:\' with '/'.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as far as I understand your question:

```
path = os.path.abspath(file_name)
print path
```

It takes a relative path and returns the absolute system path.
For me it just makes no sense. If the filename is all you have, it won't find the file anyways. If file_name is your relative path to the file, the abspath() function should work.

Comment: This doesnt work because the file is somewhere else not on this path

Comment: If your file could be **anywhere**, you won't be able to find it just by the file name. There are maybe multiple files with the **same name** and there are directories where your application **doesn't have enough rights** to access. My question: Why does the user know the filename if he doesn't know the location? And do you (dev) know the location?

Comment: I do know the location

Comment: Are the files always in the same directory?

Comment: No they are not

Comment: So they are literally anywhere? Because if they are, the easiest way is to ask the user for the complete path. You can't be sure that you have found the right file if you have found one with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the os module :https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

```
import os

file = "/Users/Test.py"
print(os.path.abspath(file))
```

Comment: `"/Users/Test.py"` is not a file_name `"Test.py"` is a file name.